# Need to fix tooltip view position

Tags: swiftui

Here I want to show the tooltip on of tap in the button. The position of the tooltip should be just the top of the `TooTipButton` and should have the dynamic height to the message text. It is used in many places in 'HStack', 'VStack's with the other content. It should fit in the layout.

For example here the code has `HStack` inside that `Text` and `TooTipButton`. But it does not show the **Text** component with the text `Created by Me`

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showing = false
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Created by Me")
                    TooTipButton(message: "hey.!! here is some view.", proxy: reader)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ToolTipMessage<Presenting>: View where Presenting: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    let presenting: () -> Presenting
    let text: String
    let proxy: GeometryProxy
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            self.presenting()
            Group {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.body)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.vertical, 8)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .shadow(radius: 6)
                    .background(Color(.systemBlue).opacity(0.96) )
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .transition(.slide)
                    .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
            }.frame(width: proxy.size.width)
        }
        .onReceive(Just(isShowing)) { shwoing in
            if shwoing {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                    self.isShowing = false
                }
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.isShowing = false
        }
    }
}


extension View {
    func toast(isShowing: Binding<Bool>, text: String, proxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        ToolTipMessage(isShowing: isShowing,
                       presenting: { self },
                       text: text,
                       proxy: proxy)
    }
}


struct TooTipButton: View {
    let message: String
    @State var showMessage = false
    let proxy: GeometryProxy
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            showMessage = true
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
        .toast(isShowing: $showMessage, text: message, proxy: proxy)
    }
}
```

Here are the images:
[image: Tooltip text]

Answer (score 0):

Using `.overlay` and `.offset` should help:

```
struct ToolTipMessage<Presenting>: View where Presenting: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    let presenting: () -> Presenting
    let text: String
    let proxy: GeometryProxy
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            self.presenting()
                .overlay {
                    Text(text)
                        .font(.body)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding(.vertical, 8)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .shadow(radius: 6)
                        .background(Color(.systemBlue).opacity(0.96) )
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                        .transition(.slide)
                        .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
                        .frame(width: proxy.size.width)
                    
                        .offset(x: 0, y: -30)
                }
        }
        .onReceive(Just(isShowing)) { shwoing in
            if shwoing {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                    self.isShowing = false
                }
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.isShowing = false
        }
    }
}
```